# Using PHP server to populate data in Word Template on client computer

Tags: php, com, ms-word

I'm getting a headache and at this point I need some help.

Basically what I have is a server (xampp) setup on my computer at work. On this server I have a script that creates and populates a Word 2007 Template with data retrieved from a database as well as user input. This part works just fine.

My issue is when I go to another computer on our network and type in the IP address for my server and go through the same process to create the file from the Word Template with all the data, the Word file opens on the server computer and not on the client computer. Does anybody know how to solve this?

This is the code for the Word Template creation page:

```
<?php
include_once 'core/classes/company.php';

$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to start Word");
$word->visible=1;
$template_file = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/portal/includes/templates/form1.dotx';
$word->Documents->Open($template_file);
//Part Number
$partNumBookMark = 'PartNum';
$objBookmark = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks($partNumBookMark);
$range = $objBookmark->Range;
$range->Text = $part_num;
//Part Name
$partNameBookMark = 'PartName';
$objBookmark = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks($partNameBookMark);
$range = $objBookmark->Range;
$range->Text = $part_name;

$word=null;
unset($word);
```

In the initialization of the COM object, I've tried `('word.application', 'localhost)` but to no avail. Again, this works just fine when I run the script from the server computer, but I can't get the Word document to appear on the client computer for final input and saving. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to tell Word to save the document to a temp file, then send the contents of that file in your HTTP response. At this point, it's just a regular file download. I'm sure you can easily find samples on how to implement that with PHP (which I'm not personally familiar with).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code and it works now for opening the documents on other computers on the network:

```
// Save document
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "word");
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($filename);

// Close and quit
$word->Quit();
unset($word);
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
//header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.docx");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

// Send file to browser

readfile($filename);
unlink($filename);
```